workbench do not read network drivers on my ubuntu desktop
I try to open a NAS driver where I have store some queries for use, but Workbench do not allow see any network or secondary HD, show, just the home directory and local folders. Outside of workbench, I can map the same driver I try to get from workbench. Using workbench in Windows 11 not have the issue. I relative new on Ubuntu desktop. Any advise or what I did wrong?
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-10-26 10:34:06

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. OptiPlex 7010
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-3570 × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)
Disk Capacity:                               3.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            A29
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-47-generic

